# Catia V5 VB.net code, how to remove popup "some contextual links will be broken"

Tags: vb.net, cad, catia

I have a Catia V5 assembly where I'd like to delete a part that is inside a product. I made the following code.
`

```
 Public Shared Function Delete_Part(Name_Of_The_Product_Instance_Containing_The_Part As String, Name_Of_The_Part_Instance_To_Delete As String)

        Dim CATIA = GetObject(, "CATIA.Application")
        Dim productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
        Dim selection1 = productDocument1.Selection
        selection1.Clear
        Dim product1 = productDocument1.Product
        Dim products1 = product1.Products
        Dim product2 = products1.Item(Name_Of_The_Product_Instance_Containing_The_Part)
        Dim products2 = product2.Products
        Dim product3 = products2.Item(Name_Of_The_Part_Instance_To_Delete)
        selection1.Add(product3)
        selection1.Clear
    End Function
```

The code works, the part is about to be delete but a warning/popup message appears saying :

***"some contextual links will be broken [...] some of the components you are trying to delete are contextual. Use change context on a new instance before synchronizing the external references "***

I can manually click on ok and the part gets deleted with no problem, but how can I automate this ?

Writing :

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Would not really be an option as it's not robust.

Comment: Instead of using the selection, try to use the _Remove_ method of the _Products_ collection. (e.g. `products2.Remove(Name_Of_The_Part_Instance_To_Delete)`)

Comment: Note: In general, `SendKeys` is the absolute last thing to use.

Comment: The solution from @Shrotter did work, another workaroud I found was to keep the same original code but before executing it, use another code that delete every external references in the part (external parameters, external geometry).  That way the popup will not appear as the part as no longer "contextual links" (meaning, the part does not rely on any other parts or products.